# Inner components state in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to solve a problem with flutter widgets tree, how to make a state for sets of widgets where inner widgets are aware of their parent state and any (non-direct) children can access to this state values read and update it. There is also a global state, that is passed when inner widgets are created, and when global state changes, widgets update their content. This was a bit abstract description of a problem and now more concrete...

I'm developing an application where I have different translations of texts. The application has a default language (state G). Then I create a tree of widgets, where I need that some inner widgets will hold and update their own language. So the root widget has state of language A. It's children have their language state B and C. Then those widgets may contain children, that depend on this language state. So set of widgets marked as D or E display text.

Example:
I have a global-state for language (G). It propagates to widgets A, B, C, D, E. When I decide to change language in the B-state widgets to Spanish, then children of B ( = D ) will update their Text and print it in Spanish. However C-state widgets (nor A or G) are not affected and display their content in French.
When I would change C-state language into English, then widgets in E will update their language and print text in English.
I also want that children could change the language of the scope where they belong. So e.g. D widgets can update B-state and set different language (but not state of A, C, G). When the A-state changes, it updates it's children as well (B,C,D,E-state = A-state)

Problems:

- If I use InheritedWidget to access nearest parent's language, I get the scope of the language. However I'm not able to update it, as it's immutable and it needs to be set from parent.
- If I wrap InheritedWidget in `StatefulWidget` I can enforce it to update the value, however I'm not able to set effectively the language from Parent widget, as the stateful widget holds it's own state and it's not updated when the parent repaints. And I don't like this approach from architectural point of view.
- Passing state into each single widget is not very nice, as many widgets on a way from G->E does not need to know about language or are system components without language state.
- I have a tree of UI state where I keep information about whole painted tree. I can write a Broadcast stream there and make my components react on this, however I don't like very much this solution.
  `Stream<Language>? parentLiveLangBroadcast; StreamController<Language>? liveLanguage;`

Any suggestions / opinions how to make this properly from architectural point of view?

[image]